# Custom Cell in table view not showing?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm having trouble getting my custom cells to show in my table view. I made sure to set the cell reuse identifier in the storyboard and connect my IBOutlets to my cell labels, but only the default cells show and not my custom ones. This is the code for my table view controller and underneath for my table view cell:

```
class HoursTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var hourDonationSegmentedButton: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var addEntryButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var editEntryButton: UIButton!

    var hoursEntries = [HoursEntry]()
    var dummyData : [HoursEntryTest] = [HoursEntryTest(hours: 1, minutes: 30, entryTitle: "title", organization: "unicef", content: "content", date: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))]
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "HoursTableViewCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareTableView()
    }

    func prepareTableView() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.register(HoursTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    }


}

    extension HoursTableViewController {

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return dummyData.count

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var cell : HoursTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HoursTableViewCell
            let hoursEntry = dummyData[indexPath.row]
            cell = setCellTextFromHoursEntry(currentCell: cell, hoursEntry: hoursEntry)

            return cell
        }

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func setCellTextFromHoursEntry(currentCell: HoursTableViewCell, hoursEntry: HoursEntryTest) -> HoursTableViewCell {
            currentCell.entryTitleLabel!.text = hoursEntry.entryTitle;
            currentCell.organizationLabel!.text = hoursEntry.organization;
            currentCell.dateLabel!.text = "placeholder date"
            currentCell.hourLabel!.text = String(hoursEntry.hours);
            currentCell.minuteLabel!.text = String(hoursEntry.minutes);

            return currentCell;
        }
}
```

```
class HoursTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var entryTitleLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    @IBOutlet var organizationLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    @IBOutlet var hourLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    @IBOutlet var minuteLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hii if it's xib file then no need to use register Method. please try this:
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HoursTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the custom cell from `Nib` file, you should define the cell in this way:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HoursTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

another point:

If you are using nib file for your custom cell and set IBOutlet, there is no need to define your elements as

```
@IBOutlet var entryTitleLabel: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()
```

you just need to set `@IBOutlet var entryTitleLabel: UILabel!`